# How to change cursor position with draft.js?

Tags: reactjs, selection, text-editor, cursor-position, draftjs

I am wondering how you can change the cursor position in draft.js after having done an text insertion on key command. Therefore I am currently using `_handleKeyCommand(cmd)` to insert a custom text block whenever the user presses a specific button. Next I tried the following:

```
currentState = this.state.editorState;
var selectionState = this.state.editorState.getSelection().getStartKey();
this.setState({editorState: EditorState.forceSelection(currentState, selectionState)});
```

But this keeps crashing with the error message

> TypeError: selection.getHasFocus is not a function

although I imported `SelectionState`. So how do I properly change the cursor position (preferably to the position before the insertion) and what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var selectionState = this.state.editorState.getSelection().getStartKey();` should be `var selectionState = this.state.editorState.getSelection()`

Comment: Nice! So how do I modify the selection state?

Comment: by `selectionState=selectionState.merge({'forceKey':xxxx, focusOffset:5})`

Comment: how to focus cursor to last character of element ?

Comment: @Anil if you mean `element` be `block`, then set `focusOffset`  to be the text length of that block.